# Receive Jsonp Callback and data from WCF Service

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

Thanks for all your fantastic help so far - I am making good progress with my little project. I am however stuck on another hurdle which I cannot get passed.

My service Interface has a function that looks like this :

```
    <OperationContract()> _
       <WebGet(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
               RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="GetCustomers?strCustomers={strCustomers}&callback={CustomerCallback}")> _
    Function GetCustomers(ByVal strCustomers As String, ByVal CustomerCallback As String) As Stream
```

This function returns the json data like this:

```
  For i = 0 To CustomerTable.Rows.Count - 1
                                CustomerRow = CustomerTable.Rows(i)
                                Dim CC As New Customers
                                CC.Code = CustomerRow.Item("Code")
                                CC.Name = CustomerRow.Item("Name")
                                CC.InternalID = CustomerRow.Item("InternalID")

                                Cust.Add(CC)


                            Next i
                            ' Serialize the results as JSON
                            Dim serializer As DataContractJsonSerializer = New DataContractJsonSerializer(Cust.GetType())
                            Dim Stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream

                            serializer.WriteObject(Stream, Cust)

                            ' Return the results serialized as JSON
                            Dim strJson As String = Encoding.Default.GetString(Stream.ToArray())

                            Dim jsCode As String = CustomerCallback & "(" & strJson & ")" '"({""Status"":""OK""});"

                            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/javascript"
                            Return New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsCode))
```

OK, so now this sends the callback function to my jquery / ajax function that is supposed to use this data. this is my ajax call:

var customStore = new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
        load: function () {

```
         return  $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                data: {},
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result.strCustomers);

                },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(status));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

         });

    },
    totalCount: function(loadOptions) {
    return 0;
}
});
```

This code executes without any errors whatsoever, so the way of doing this should be right, from my side.

The problem is that I cannot get this data to show in a datagrid; so I think I am not actually getting the right data, eventhough there are no errors.

I want to know:

Have I sent the data from my WCF service through correctly?
How do I use the actual data further in my jquery page?

The whole thing is, I need to get all the customers from my WCF service, through a cross domain call ( hwich I have managed ) and then display all this customers in a devextreme datagrid:

```
var gridDataSourceConfiguration = {
    store: customStore
};

var dataGridOptions = {
    dataSource: gridDataSourceConfiguration,
    filterRow: {
        visible: ko.observable(true),
        applyFilter: ko.observable("auto")
    },
    searchPanel: {
        visible: true,
        width: 240,
        placeholder: 'Search...'
    },
    headerFilter: {
        visible: true
    },
    columns: [{
        dataField: "InternalID",
        width: 30,
        caption: "ID"
    }, {
        dataField: 'Name',
        alignment: 'right'
    }, {
        dataField: "Code",
        alignment: 'right'
    }
    ]
};
```

So, how can I get the data into the datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have watsed your precious time, but I have solved it. I had an issue on code that I have not posted above.

Comment: I think it's better than to delete the question.